# Equivalent of pyinstaller for freezing python,html, and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, pyinstaller

I want to create a web app which I don't want to host but keep it on localhost itself similarly to a Desktop application. Basically I want an **icon on the Desktop which will open the application on the localhost** . The application is developed using HTML,CSS,Javascript and flask framework of python. **Pyinstaller** is a way to do this but it doesn't support JavaScript and I have lots of that in my app. Is it possible? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make a script that first starts the flask webapp on localhost and then starts a webbrowser at `localhost:5000`

Answer (score 0):

Just a commentary (I hope it helps):

1. I created a slideshow in wordpress localhost.
2. I froze it with webcopy.
3. Install in any pc with innosetup

best